# Force Paging Library to make Api Request

Tags: android, pagination, datasource, android-room, android-paging

I have successfully implemented a PagedList.BoundaryCallback, which loads a list of upcoming movies from "themoviedb" database, and saves the response into the database.
But it does not work the way I want it. Since the request return a list of upcoming movies, the response changes frequently. But if I already have data in my database, the onZeroItemsLoaded() method is not called.
My question is, how can I force the data source, or this boundary callback to always make an api request, and refresh the content of my database from the network?

```
public class UpcomingMoviesBoundaryCallback extends PagedList.BoundaryCallback<MovieListItemEntity> {
public static final String TAG = UpcomingMoviesBoundaryCallback.class.getSimpleName();

private UpcomingMoviesRepository upcomingMoviesRepository;
private int page = 1;

public UpcomingMoviesBoundaryCallback(UpcomingMoviesRepository upcomingMoviesRepository) {
    this.upcomingMoviesRepository = upcomingMoviesRepository;
}

@Override
public void onZeroItemsLoaded() {
    super.onZeroItemsLoaded();
    Log.d(TAG, "onZeroItemsLoaded: ");
    load();
}

@Override
public void onItemAtEndLoaded(@NonNull MovieListItemEntity itemAtEnd) {
    super.onItemAtEndLoaded(itemAtEnd);
    Log.d(TAG, "onItemAtEndLoaded: ");
    load();
}

@SuppressLint("CheckResult")
private void load() {
    upcomingMoviesRepository.getUpcoming(page)
            .doOnSuccess(result -> {
                upcomingMoviesRepository.saveUpcomingMovies(result);
                page = result.getPage() + 1;
            })
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribe(result -> {
                Log.d(TAG, "load: " + result);
            }, error -> {
                Log.d(TAG, "load: error", error);
            });
}
```

}

```
public class UpcomingMoviesRepositoryImpl implements UpcomingMoviesRepository {
private static final String TAG = UpcomingMoviesRepository.class.getSimpleName();

private MovieResponseMapper movieResponseMapper = new MovieResponseMapper();
private MovieAppApi mMovieAppApi;
private UpcomingDao mUpcomingDao;

public UpcomingMoviesRepositoryImpl(MovieAppApi mMovieAppApi, UpcomingDao mUpcomingDao) {
    this.mMovieAppApi = mMovieAppApi;
    this.mUpcomingDao = mUpcomingDao;
}

@Override
public Single<MovieListResponse> getUpcoming(int page) {
    return mMovieAppApi.upcoming(page);
}

@Override
public Single<MovieListResponse> getUpcoming() {
    return mMovieAppApi.upcoming();
}

@Override
public void saveUpcomingMovies(MovieListResponse movieListResponse) {
    Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().execute(() -> {
        long[] inseted = mUpcomingDao.save(movieResponseMapper.map2(movieListResponse.getResults()));
        Log.d(TAG, "saveUpcomingMovies: " + inseted.length);
    });
}

@Override
public LiveData<PagedList<MovieListItemEntity>> getUpcomingLiveData() {
    PagedList.Config config = new PagedList.Config.Builder()
            .setEnablePlaceholders(true)
            .setPageSize(12)
            .build();
    DataSource.Factory<Integer, MovieListItemEntity> dataSource = mUpcomingDao.upcoming();
    LivePagedListBuilder builder =
            new LivePagedListBuilder(dataSource, config)
            .setBoundaryCallback(new UpcomingMoviesBoundaryCallback(this));
    return builder.build();
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the repository you can query database to check if data is old then you can start an async network call that will write the result directly to the database. Because the database is being observed, the UI bound to the `LiveData<PagedList>` will update automatically to account for the new dataset.

```
@Override
public LiveData<PagedList<MovieListItemEntity>> getUpcomingLiveData() {
    if(mUpcomingDao.isDatasetValid()) //Check last update time or creation date and invalidate data if needed
        upcomingMoviesRepository.getUpcoming()
            .doOnSuccess(result -> {
                upcomingMoviesRepository.clearUpcomingMovies()
                upcomingMoviesRepository.saveUpcomingMovies(result);
            })
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribe(result -> {
                Log.d(TAG, "load: " + result);
            }, error -> {
                Log.d(TAG, "load: error", error);
            });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a great idea. But what I really wanted to achieve is to load the data from the network every time when I open the app with available internet connection.

Comment: That is actually easier, you just have to clear your database before returning new DataSource in getUpcomingLiveData(). The BoundaryCallback take care of fetching new data.

Comment: If you want to load the new data when showing existing data you have to create and pass a LiveData that indicate the loading status and when reload is complete just update your db and show the new DataSource.